# Help me to find a statistical rule/law which most closely matches a fixed set of numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, curves

I am hoping someone can help me with this problem! I have a distribution of 2000 numbers but I only know the first 10. The first 10 numbers are: 
2025, 1000, 335, 300, 187.5, 135, 99.5, 20, 17.5, and 13.5. I know that the total of all 2000 numbers is about 12,000.

What I am looking for is a recognised long tail curve model which using the first 10 numbers only predicts a total for all 2000 numbers in the sequence. I need the total to ideally be between 11,000 and 13,000. I did look at Zipfs law but I'm not sure this works.

I am not a mathematician but would appreciate any models/distribution curves/laws you could suggest and what the model you suggest would give as a total knowing just the first 10 numbers. The key thing that I am trying to do is fit these numbers to a recognised curve / long tail distrubtion model. I am less bothered about the total (akthough ideally in the range 11000-13000) and more bothered about the model being something that would be recognised by mathematicians globally.

I hope this is clear. Thank you so much in advance to anyone who tries to solve this for me!

Comment: If I were to do this I would use Q-Q plot against standard distributions.  This consists of your values, low to high, against standard distributions.  For a good simple example, you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_probability_plot.  Ignore the Q-Q plot for now and understand normal.  Then you can mentally go over to Q-Q plots.   Bear in mind that all you are ever going to get is a good, perhaps adequate, description.  Don't let the "best" defeat the good.   I have used the  R-language to do similar tasks, but the Q-Q link has "notes" that suggest other packages.  more..

Comment: I always do the fit until the residuals are Gaussian (i.e. straight in a normal probability plot (within limits).  Look at those things I mentioned and if you are comfortable I can try that technique but ...   its been some time and I am old so it would take some time.

Comment: I stumbled across https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/787/lectures-quantiles.pdf    Which has examples _very_ similar to your problem.